# Upgrading my app to Rails 5. Not sure what to make of errors on bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

I changed the rails line in my app's Gemfile from:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
```

To:

```
gem 'rails', '5.0.0'
```

Per the rails documentation on the upgrade process. I then ran `bundle update rails`. I then hit a roadblock:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
dotenv-rails (= 2.0.2) was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
  railties (~> 4.0)

rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  railties (= 5.0.0)
```

As I understand, railties is part of rails? So that seemed weird. To humor the error, I added:

```
gem 'railties', '5.0.0'
```

Then `bundle update railties` yields:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activerecord (= 4.2.3)

  In Gemfile:
    annotate was resolved to 2.7.2, which depends on
      activerecord (< 6.0, >= 3.2)

rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  activerecord (= 5.0.0)
```

I follow the rabbithole and add:

```
gem 'activerecord', '5.0.0'
```

`bundle update activerecord` yields...

```
You have requested:
  railties = 5.0.0

The bundle currently has railties locked at 4.2.3.
Try running `bundle update railties`
```

The whole reason I am even updating active record is so that I can update railties... it's running me in circles.

If I run `bundle update` with my full Gemfile now (activerecord and railties added):

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    devise (~> 3.5.6) was resolved to 3.5.6, which depends on
      railties (< 5, >= 3.2.6)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.0)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.0)
```

I'll admit I'm not a total pro at this process. Is there anything I am missing? Has anyone experienced something like this during their upgrade process?

Comment: Have you tried deleting `Gemfile.lock` and re-running `bundle`? Sometimes that does the trick

Comment: @NickM I did just try that. Unfortunately I am faced with that final error once more (the one talking about devise).

Comment: Don't delete the `Gemfile.lock`! You will loose the benefits of semantic versioning, jumping up to versions you might not be ready for.

Comment: Did you install rails 5? Instead of just changing the `Gemfile`...

Comment: go to 4.2.10 release first and address the deprecation errors if any... then jump to 5 good luck!

Comment: @engineerDave Yes  - good call. I jumped to 4.2.10. There were no deprecation messages - it came out all fine. So I was pleased with that. 

But sure enough, as soon as I type in 5.0.0... kersplat. Been combing through gems all day trying to see what I have to change to get it to bundle correctly.

Comment: You might have to check your gemfile and remove the explicit version requirements on the gems that are erring. FWIW if you're using this guide, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-2-to-rails-5-0, the upgrade for me was pretty smooth. Also use the spermy operator, ~>,  on the versions. This will honor semver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error means `bundle update dotenv-rails`, if you are restricting the version make sure it's to one that supports railties 5. Based on your updates, it seems you are in a older *devise* too. So try to update both at the same time:

`bundle update dotenv-rails devise`, make sure you read the update notes in dotenv-rails and devise and change anything that needs to be change in your code.

**My advise**: go to the closest version that supports rails 5 first, so for devise that's 4.0.3 and dotenv-rails 2.1.2. Set this restrictions in your *Gemfile* before you `bundle update`. Only after you update this gems successfully attempt to update rails. Add any other gem that comes up to this same process.